# using jo with aws invoke lambda command line

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jo

Normally, to test my aws lambda functions, Id do this:

```
IMG_FILE='/some/image/loc//img.jpg' &&\
jo img=%"$IMG_FILE" | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- "$LAMBDA_HOST" >> output.bin
```

Id like to replicate the same with aws lambda invoke function like so:

```
IMG_FILE='/some/image/loc//img.jpg' &&\
jo img=%"$IMG_FILE" |aws lambda invoke --payload XXXXXX --function-name funky_func output.bin
```

How do I pass the `jo` output to the `--payload` param? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, looking at [the documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html), it appears that `--payload` can take a `file://` parameter. So you can do:

```
IMG_FILE='/some/image/loc/img.jpg' &&
  jo img=%"$IMG_FILE" > img.json &&
  aws lambda invoke --payload file://img.json \
    --function-name funky_func output.bin
```

...but it's possible you'll hit some limitation on command line length depending on the size of your image.

---

It's *possible* -- but I'm unable to test this at the moment -- that if you were to provide a file argument of `file:///dev/stdin` that you could provide the JSON on stdin. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: yea the whole point of using jo was to not do this :(

Comment: I've read the documentation for you and suggested and alternative.

Comment: yea.. I tried this option `--payload file://img.json` aswell.. but for some weird reason, it litters/outputs on my terminal with the payload contents and there is no `output.bin` :( so bizzare.

Comment: I tried this aswell now `file:///dev/stdin` again, it just outputs the json on my terminal.... odd..